# No XMPP client to talk to, us (partial JID) : asterisk

Tags: voip, google-talk, google-voice

I am attempting to setup asterisk with my google voice account and not having much success.  When I attempt to dial out, I get this error:

```
No XMPP client to talk to, us (partial JID) : asterisk
Unable to create channel of type 'Gtalk' (cause 0 - Unknown)
  == Everyone is busy/congested at this time (1:0/0/1)
    -- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/WalterWhite-00000000' status is 'CHANUNAVAIL'
```

I followed the documentation from here:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Calling+using+Google
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ec8nsZORSBw

I am running Asterisk 1.8.7.0 on ArchLinux.  I can post my configuration files if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working;however, the call quality is not that great all the time.  The first minute is usually good depending on who I call.  After that, the call quality may drop off quite a bit.

I set my configuration up using this as a baseline:
http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=79677&p=162610&hilit=google+voice&sid=8568c94ac82b7ab351033c642beefefe#p162610

Walter